# Opening frame content in a new tab

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Iam trying to reduce my file sizes by reformatting my site to use the one main index page with an iframe to display the content. However, I want to be able to give my viewers the opportunity to open the contents of the iframe into a new tab to print without printing all of the ads which appear on my index page. I have tried writing a java applet that will identify whatever contents are currently displayed in the iframe and open the file in a new tab with no success. CSS, jquery, javascripts, and php have likewise been of no help in this situation. I do not want to creat two separate links for everything one targeting the iframe and the other targeting a new tab. I want one link that when clicked it will open whatever file is displayed in the frame into a new tab. Am I hoping for too much or is it possible to create such a script?

Comment: Why do you want to display your site in an iFrame? Why do you want to reduce file sizes?  Does it make life easier for your visitors or more difficult?

Comment: I'm changing the format because my host has me limited in the space I can use and this format looks most appealing of all the other space saving options I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the `target="_blank"` attritube in the link, if not, it isn't really clear to me what you mean

Comment: A sorry. My iframe (iframe name="body") by default displays my main content page (main.html) however each of my links load into the iframe when selected. (say offer.html) What I would like is a link that will detect the file curerently displayed in the iframe and load it into a new tab using target="_blank" Something like <a href src="parent.main.BODY.document" target="_blank">Link</a> where BODY is the name of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target="_parent"` attribute on a link within the iFrame.

Comment: The problem is, some of the content that will be loaded into the iframe does not allow for hyperlinks. I have some script files that will load into it such as css, js, .c, etc. A link outside the iframe in the main index file that will identify the displayed content and open it into a new page solves the problem of trying to insert hyperlinks into each display file especially those that don't display html content.

Answer (score 0):

css seems to be the way to go.

You could assign to everything outside the iframe a class "NotForPrint". Then you would use the media attribute and have two different stylesheets on your page, one for media screen and the other for media print. The media print stylesheet would hide all except the iframe. Or you could have a "Print Preview" button, and onclick have a JavaScript function toggle the NotForPrint class display.

The opposite works too, assigning a class of "ForPrint" to the iframe.

In this scenario you don't use a new tab, everything happens in the same window.

Comment: Interesting. I think I have an old css framebuster I can modify for this. This could be a perfect example of being too close to the problem.

Comment: I tried a couple of frame busters using css javascript and dhtml but they didn't produce the results I wanted. I came across the following code that looks like it should give me what I want but can't get it to work.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      function getContentFromIframe(bodyFrame) {
        var myIFrame = document.getElementById(bodyFrame);
        var content = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(‘MSIE’) != -1 ? myIFrame.contentWindow.document : myIFrame.contentDocument;
        return content;
      };
    </script>


            <a href="#" onClick="getContentFromIframe" target="_new">Print</a> <font size="1px">(Opens in a new tab)</font>
If you visit the test site I set up you can see what I am trying to do. Maybe we can figure this out. [link](http://www.fanficcollection.com/)

Comment: onClick="getContentFromIframe()" but this is just capturing the content, it's not going to write it in a new window.